# Unique representation of simple function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, simple-functions

**Claim**: Consider a simple function $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ where $(X,M,\mu)$ is a measure space. If we represent $f$ as $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} \chi_{A_i}$, with $A_i \cap A_j = \varnothing$ and $a_i \ne a_j$ for $i \ne j$, then is this representation of the simple function is unique.

I intuitively feel it should be true, but I'm not able to prove it.

My attempt at proof: Suppose $f = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} \chi_{A_i} = \sum_{j=1}^{m} b_{j} \chi_{B_j}$. Then we need to prove the following: $n=m$, $a_i = b_{p_i}$ and $A_i = B_{p_i}$, where $p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ and $p_i \ne p_j$ if $i \ne j$. However, I'm stuck at this point and do not know how to proceed.

I have two questions:

1. Could you suggest how do I complete the proof or some other method to prove the claim, or a counterexample to the claim?
2. If the claim is true, does it hold without can $a_i \ne a_j$ be removed from the hypothesis, and then established as a part of the proof?

Comment: Second, note that $\chi_A=\chi_A+0\chi_B$; to get uniqueness up to reordering you need to assume $a_j\ne0$ and $b_j\ne0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I did not understand what $\chi_A+$ means. And yes I understand what you mean by uniqueness upto reordering. I have edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: I didn't write $\chi_A+$. I pointed out that $\chi_A=\chi_A+0\chi_B$.

Comment: In the first comment you have used $\chi_A+ = -\chi_B$, and I did not understand what this means.

Comment: must have been a typo - the first comment is gone.

Comment: in any case in the first remaining comment I give you a counterexample to the current version - you need to assume the coefficients are non-zero.

Comment: what if the function takes the value zero over some $B \subset X$? then would the representation of the function would always be non unique? and with the assumption you stated how would we prove the claim?

Comment: Oh for heaven's sake. Let $n=1$, $A_1=[0,1]$, $a_1=1$. Let $m=2$, $b_1=a_1$, $B_1=A_1$, $b_2=0$, $B_2=[4,5]$, Than all your hypotheses hold but $a_1\chi_{A_1}=b_1\chi_{B_1}+b_2\chi_{B_2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's easy to construct examples showing that you need to assume $$a_j\ne0$$ and $$b_k\ne0.$$ IF you assume that:

> > **HINT** Show that $f(X)\setminus\{0\}=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$.

Hence $$\{b_1,\dots,b_m\}=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\},$$ and now since the $a_j$ are distinct and the $b_k$ are distinct you're on your way...

**Note** another way to fix it is to assume that $\bigcup A_j=X$. (If you assume that you had better *not* assume $a_j\ne0$.) The stuff at the start maybe comes out more elegant with the second version, but once we've moved on the second seems silly, requiring $\chi_A+0\chi_{X\setminus A}$ in place of a simple $\chi_A$.